# Load numpy array to imagebuff

Tags: python, texturing, game-engine

I need to load a 4 channel numpy array to the gl image buffer so I can swap it out using the bge texture module.

More generally I've installed opencv in blender and would like to display the results of a cv operation in the render window. I can send the results of "texture.ImageRender(scene, camera)" to a numpy array and use them in opencv but I currently have to view the results in a separate cv pop-up window.

Anyone have any experience with this because I'm not having much luck with the documentation.

Comment: cannot be done using imagebuff. see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48416/passing-bge-texture-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limitations in the API prevent bge.texture.ImageBuff from accepting outside arrays even if they match the flat structure of regular bge arrays.